# Preencher zeros à esquerda em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Preciso inserir zeros à esquerda em um campo `input text`. Sendo que este campo
pode ser até **5 caracteres + um dígito verificador** Ou seja, preciso que o JavaScript preencha com zeros à esquerda de acordo com o que o usuário digitar, por exemplo:

```
123451 = 12345-1
12341 = 01234-1
```

ou

```
1236 = 00123-6
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Pode fazer uma função para corrigir o valor desse input. Algo como:

```js
function pad(str, length) {
  const resto = length - String(str).length;
  return '0'.repeat(resto > 0 ? resto : '0') + str;
}

// exemplo de testes
var testes = [1, 10, 100, 1000];
testes.forEach((teste) => {
  var resultado = pad(teste, 3);
  console.log(resultado);
});
```

Adaptado ao teu caso ficaria assim:

```js
function ajustarInput(str) {
  var adicionar = 6 - str.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < adicionar; i++) str = '0' + str;
  return str.slice(0, 5) + '-' + str.slice(-1);
}

document.getElementById('teste').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var input = document.getElementById('input');
  input.value = ajustarInput(input.value);
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" />
<button id="teste">Corrigir</button>
```

Essa função lê quantos caracteres faltam à string, e junta-lhe zeros. Depois separa o ultimo caractere e insere um `-` antes de retornar a nova string.

Comment: Perfeito!! @sergio precisava de algo prático

Answer (score 10):

Basta usar esta operação na *string*:

```
("000000"+str).slice(-6,-1)+'-'+("0"+str).slice(-1)
```

Se quiser incrementar, pode fazer um filtro antes, para remover os não numéricos:

```
str="000000"+str.replace(/\D/g,'');
str=str.slice(-6,-1)+'-'+str.slice(-1);
```

### Demonstração:

```js
document.getElementById('format').addEventListener('click', function () {
    var input = document.getElementById( 'entrada' );
    
    input.value="000000"+input.value.replace(/\D/g,'');
    input.value=input.value.slice(-6,-1)+'-'+input.value.slice(-1);
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="entrada">
<button id="format">Formatar</button><br>
```

Comment: nãssa, campeão isto aqui e +1+ pelo stack fiddle . . . com perdão da mágica do Sergio, o checkmark podia muito bem vir pra cá

Comment: ok foi a implementação que não funcionou @brasofilo o código é bom minha implementação que não rolou.

Comment: A implementação do comentário aqui também não rolou, @Ivan :D Você tava querendo replicar na [resposta do Renan](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/37313/preencher-zeros-%c3%a0-esquerda-em-javascript/37322?noredirect=1#comment71970_37314) :))

Answer (score 6):

É só fazer algo do tipo:

```
var foo; // preencha esta variável com o seu texto.
/* sério, preencha foo. */
foo += ""; // só por paranóia. Se foo não era string até aqui, depois desta linha será.

while (foo.length < 5) {
    foo = "0" + foo;
}
// agora coloque foo de novo na caixa de texto.
```

Se o texto tiver cinco caracteres ou mais, ele pula o laço. Caso contrário, o código concatenará zeros a esquerda até que a string tenha cinco caracteres.

Note que esse código funciona para o texto a esquerda do seu dígito verificador. Você deve depois concatenar o dígito verificador no final do resultado.

Comment: entendi a lógica mas não funcionou a tua função @renan

Comment: A função funciona beleza, @Ivan, provavelmente foi a sua implementação que bugou ;)

Comment: Funcionar, funciona, se o conteúdo de `foo` vier como string de antemão. Se um número (casos mais comuns para se simular um *zerofill* desse tipo) ela falha porque o objeto Number não tem uma propriedade *length*. Nada que um `foo = foo.toString();` antes do loop não resolva.

Comment: @BrunoAugusto editei a resposta pra levar isso em consideração, valeu :)

Comment: Eu mudaria pra `foo.toString()`. Pelo menos não cheira a gambiarra.

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que isso já resolva:

```
const n = '1236'
(n.slice(0, -1) + '-' + n.slice(-1)).padStart(7, '0')
```

Para um exemplo mais detalhado:

```js
const inputNumber = document.getElementById('number')
inputNumber.addEventListener('keyup', e => handleDigits(e.currentTarget))
handleDigits(inputNumber)

function handleDigits(field) {
  let n = field.value.replace(/[^\d]/, '').replace(/^0+/, '')
  n = n || '0'
  
  const digitsBeforeTheHyphen = n.slice(0, -1)
  const lastDigit = n.slice(-1)
  const digitsWithHyphen = digitsBeforeTheHyphen + '-' + lastDigit
  const zeroesIncluded = digitsWithHyphen.padStart(7, '0')
  
  field.value = zeroesIncluded
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="number" value="1236">
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a função padStart de String.prototype.padStart()
Essa função recebe 2 parametros na qual o primeiro é do tipo number que representa o comprimento da string resultante e o segundo parametro é o caractere, ou caracteres, que deve preencher a string alvo. Caso o comprimento dessa essa string de preenchimento seja superior ao targetLength, ela será truncada a partir da direita

Exemplo:

```
const str1 = '5';

console.log(str1.padStart(3, '0'));
// Saída experada: "005"
```

Answer (score 0):

Tem ainda a [implementação](http://phpjs.org/functions/str_pad/) em JavaScript do str_pad() do PHP feita pelo pessoal do PHP.JS:

```js
function str_pad(input, pad_length, pad_string, pad_type) {
  //  discuss at: http://phpjs.org/functions/str_pad/
  // original by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
  // improved by: Michael White (http://getsprink.com)
  //    input by: Marco van Oort
  // bugfixed by: Brett Zamir (http://brett-zamir.me)
  //   example 1: str_pad('Kevin van Zonneveld', 30, '-=', 'STR_PAD_LEFT');
  //   returns 1: '-=-=-=-=-=-Kevin van Zonneveld'
  //   example 2: str_pad('Kevin van Zonneveld', 30, '-', 'STR_PAD_BOTH');
  //   returns 2: '------Kevin van Zonneveld-----'

  var half = '',
    pad_to_go;

  var str_pad_repeater = function(s, len) {
    var collect = '',
      i;

    while (collect.length < len) {
      collect += s;
    }
    collect = collect.substr(0, len);

    return collect;
  };

  input += '';
  pad_string = pad_string !== undefined ? pad_string : ' ';

  if (pad_type !== 'STR_PAD_LEFT' && pad_type !== 'STR_PAD_RIGHT' && pad_type !== 'STR_PAD_BOTH') {
    pad_type = 'STR_PAD_RIGHT';
  }
  if ((pad_to_go = pad_length - input.length) > 0) {
    if (pad_type === 'STR_PAD_LEFT') {
      input = str_pad_repeater(pad_string, pad_to_go) + input;
    } else if (pad_type === 'STR_PAD_RIGHT') {
      input = input + str_pad_repeater(pad_string, pad_to_go);
    } else if (pad_type === 'STR_PAD_BOTH') {
      half = str_pad_repeater(pad_string, Math.ceil(pad_to_go / 2));
      input = half + input + half;
      input = input.substr(0, pad_length);
    }
  }

  return input;
}

document.getElementById( 'test' ).innerHTML = str_pad( 10, 5, 0, 'STR_PAD_LEFT' );
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

O interessante dessa função, além da parametrização completa (não apenas da string de entrada) é que considera outros cenários desnecessários ao tópico mas úteis em outras circunstâncias.

Comment: Vish... O *snippet* até funciona, mas o post ficou muito feio >.<