# Gerar números aléatorios de 4 digitos [0000-9999]

Tags: javascript

Segue o exemplo abaixo do que está acontecendo, eu declarei 1198805-
e o restante é gerado.
Porem com esse defeito abaixo.

> ```
> 1198805522
> 11988052636
> 11988054970
> 1198805929
> 11988054269
> 11988054150
> 1198805671
> 1198805848
> 11988055359
> ```

Segue o Códgio em Javascript usado :

```js
var maximo = 8999;
var resultados = 40;
var stop;
var contador = 0;
 //var txt = document.getElementById("txtsenha").value;
    var txt = "11" + "" + "9" + "9204" + "-";
   // document.getElementById(el).innerHTML += txt + x + "<br>";
 document.getElementById('contadorrr').innerHTML = '<font color=#FFF size="6"> <b>-</b>Loanding<b>-</b> </font><font size="29">[</font><font size="59" color=#1E90FF> ' + contador + '</font><font size="29">]</font><font size="29" color=#1E90FF>' ;

var i, arr = [];
for (i = 0; i < maximo; i++) {
    arr[i] = i + 1;
}

var p, n, tmp;
for (p = arr.length; p;) {
    n = Math.random() * p-- | 0;
    tmp = arr[n];
    arr[n] = arr[p];
    arr[p] = tmp;
 }

for (var i = 0; i < resultados; i++) {
 document.getElementById('out').innerHTML += txt + arr[i]+ '<br> ';
}
```

```html
   </head>
<body style="background-image:url(https://i.ytimg.com/vi/gJ16uN47EAk/maxresdefault.jpg);">
<hr>
        <div class="configdiv" align="center"  style="color: #F8F8FF;">
<p><font size="15">-</font> <font size="7" color="#B5B5B5">SPACE GHOST V1.0</font> <font size="15">-</font></p> 

                <img align="center" src="http://img15.deviantart.net/49f9/i/2015/167/5/2/space_ghost_logo_by_topher147-d8x52wm.png" width="300" height="250" >
    
    
<div id="contadorrr"><font size="20" color="#FFD700"><strong></strong></font></div>
<br><br><HR>


<hr>

<font size="20" color="#20B2AA">[</font> <font size="20" color="#D3D3D3"><strong> NUMEROS </strong></font> <font size="20" color="#20B2AA">]</font>
<div id="out" align="center"  style="color: #00BFFF;"></div>
<hr></hr>
<div id="interval" align="center" style="color: #00FF00;"></div>
```

Os 4 digitos sorteados , somam o total de 5040 combinações diferente sem repetição
Porem no meu código ele gera linhas quebradas de 10, as vezes de 12 digitos, e isso interfere no total de resultados REAIS(11 digitos)

Alguem sabe como limitar o código a gerar apenas 11 digitos ?

Obrigado.

Comment: Conforme já explicado na versão deletada da mesma pergunta, o essencial é isto: [Preencher zeros à esquerda em JavaScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/37313/70)

Comment: E a parte de embaralhar sem repetir está aqui: [Números aleatórios sem repetição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10282/70)

Comment: Obrigado @Bacco foi mal pela outra pergunta, não tinha compreendido o que vc passou , obrigado msm

Comment: O importante é que resolveu. Com o tempo vc vai pegando o jeitão do site e aproveitando melhor. É que quase sempre que tem algo pronto no site, a gente já aponta, tanto para adiantar a solução quando possível, como para ajudar outros colegas com o mesmo problema (e quando há indicação de duplicata, é mera organização, para concentrar todas as respostas num mesmo lugar, não é punição e nem sinal de nada necessariamente errado com a sua pergunta). Sempre que ficar em duvida ou achar algo estranho, basta deixar um comentário (não no corpo da pergunta) que tem bastante gente querendo ajudar.

Comment: E logo que tiver mais uns pontinhos, vai poder participar do chat da rede, que é uma maneira rápida de tirar duvidas de como melhorar ou encontrar uma postagem sobre determinado assunto, ou qualquer duvida ou idéia que não caiba bem no formato pergunta-resposta.

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção, ja fiz minha parte e liberei o chat, pena que não tem tantas pessoas interessados em javascript , mas vai ser bem mais util usar o chat realmente ,to lendo umas apostila que achei no google, mas tem coisa que só alguém explicando mesmo para aprende, se você é da área de javas , vai me ver mt por aqui kkk

Comment: Em horário comercial junta mais gente. O Chat é bom pra coisas mais interativas. Perguntas objetivas é bom fazer aqui mesmo, assim ajuda mais pessoas, e fica organizado. Se tiver interesse e tempo, temos a [help] que tem umas dicas legais, e tem o site [meta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com), que é "o site sobre o site". No meta a gente não discute programação em si, mas discute os padrões do site, o que é ou não aceito, e ajuda a moldar a comunidade. É uma boa fonte de leitura sobre os comportamentos e metodologias usados no site principal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
function pad(str, length) {
  const resto = length - String(str).length;
  return '0'.repeat(resto > 0 ? resto : '0') + str;
}

var resultados =5040;
var maximo = 9999;
var arr = [];
while(arr.length < resultados){
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * maximo)
    random = pad(random, 4);
    if(arr.indexOf(random) > -1) continue;
    arr[arr.length] = random;
    console.log("11" + "" + "9" + "8805" + random);
}
```

Comment: Cara mas assim ele não vai duplicas os resultados? levando em consideração que 4 dígitos é total de 5.040 combinações(contando com **ZERO**), meu código ja evita duplicado para mim obter o resultado total , porem ele quebra os dígitos de 4 para 3 ou de 4 para 5(como uma contagem e ele continua contando....) , eu quero evitar isso e determina resultado TOTAL de **11** dígitos e **4** dígitos gerados e sem duplicados . e se eu colocar o zero na frente dos gerados ? ou usar algo parecido como `length` sendo [0000-9999] e não [0-9999]

Comment: +1, resolveu o pad e o range depois do ultimo edit. fica a sugestão de quem for usar na prática trocar o algoritmo de sorteio apenas, mas isso é um detalhe de implementação.

Comment: Bacco eu editei a resposta conforme suas orientações. Realmente Fisher-Yates é bem mais performático (até 10x e umas 8x no caso de 5040 números) o que resultaria em 3 milissegundos de diferença.
OBS: fiz essas observações segundo essa análise de Fisher-Yates x brute force: http://www.freefour.com/analysis-of-a-brute-force-shuffle/

Comment: foi bem mais rápido mesmo , ótima dica mesmo